# How to redefine a beamer template

Tags: beamer

To modify the definition of a command we use `\renewcommand`, but how about modify a beamer template.
For example if we change `itemize item` like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{triangle}
{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
```

We get the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@triangle already
>   defined.

This is an example of that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{triangle}
    {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[tiangle]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The effect of `\defbeamertemplate` is to install (`beamer`'s jargon) the option specified in `<predefined option>` for the template whose name is `<element name>`. The command has  the following (simplified) syntax:

```
\defbeamertemplate{<element name>}{<predefined option>}[<argument number>][<default optional argument>]{<predefined text>}
```

Since `itemize item` with predefined option `triangle` has already been installed (for example, in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty` and `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`), your attempt obviously produces an error.

To prevent this, you can use another string for the predefined option

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{mytriangle}
{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
```

and then

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[mytriangle]
```

A compete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{mytriangle}
    {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[mytriangle]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting lists:

[image]

If you use the starred version then, besides setting the predefined template option, `\setbeamertemplate` is immediately used for this option. So

```
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{mytriangle}
{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
```

is equivalent to

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{mytriangle}
{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}       
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[mytriangle]
```

Look at the following example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{mytriangle}
    {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Another option, if you want to overwrite the original installment of an element is to first undefine the conflicting command. For example, when you use

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{triangle}{<definition>}
```

the command `\beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@triangle` (notice the space in the name) gets internally defined using \newcommand (that's why simply trying to do another

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{triangle}{<definition>}
```

will trigger an error). You can prevent the error by undefining the command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@triangle\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{triangle}
    {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]

\begin{itemize}
\item 
text 
\item 
text
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```