# Problem using xepersian with beamer

Tags: beamer, right-to-left, xepersian

I am using `xepersian` with `beamer` and I have a problem with list environments, e.g. `itemize` and `enumerate`. I cannot flush them to the right (make them right-aligned). As you can see in the MWE, I have tried `setRL`, `setRTL` and `flushright`, but they have no effect on the slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/

\begin{document}
\begin{persian}

\begin{frame}{مشکل لیست}
  \begin{flushright}
  متن نمونه
  \end{flushright}

  \setRL
  {
    \begin{itemize}
      \item مورد اول
    \end{itemize}
  }

  \begin{flushright}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item مورد اول
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{flushright}

\end{frame}

\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

P.S. It is probably pushing it, but can I do something so the triangle in `itemize` points to the left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multi problems in the alignment of texts when using RTL languages in beamer with `xelatex`, not currently have a comprehensive solution.

In my case, I use some tricks and I suspect it work for you:

1. To right align main text in the frames you can use `\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}`
2. To right align lists after the beginning of the list environment put `\raggedleft`,  you can add a command `\RTlist` to control  item right margin.
3. For triangle of bullet  points to the left, you can take a look at my [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251184/how-to-redefine-a-beamer-template) and the detailed answer from @GonzaloMedina.

And here your MWE with those changes

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin} 
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt%
 \hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball] % or circle 

\begin{document}
\begin{persian}
\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}

\begin{frame}{مشکل لیست}
  متن نمونه

 \begin{itemize}\RTList
      \item مورد اول
 \end{itemize}


 \begin{enumerate}\RTList
      \item مورد اول
      \begin{enumerate}\RTList
      \item  مورد اول
      \item  مورد ثان
      \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}


\end{frame}

\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

[image]