# What is preventing progress bar in beamer from showing up?

Tags: beamer, xetex

I'd like to add a progress bar to my presentation (I got the idea from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer)) but I believe something is preventing it from showing up in output and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig, subfigure}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

}
  \useinnertheme{circles}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

    \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

    \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
  \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=green,fg=black}


\AtBeginEnvironment{exampleblock}{\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=gray}}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{IRNazli}
\newfontfamily\latinfontsf[Script=Latin,Scale=0.3]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{IRNazli}
\newfontfamily\digitfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{IRNazli}
\newfontfamily{\F}{IRNazli} % Farsi
\newfontfamily{\I}{IranNastaliq} % Farsi
\newfontfamily{\C}{Calibri}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{2}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
% ======================================================
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\f@size}{10}{7}{7}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{arabic split theme}
{

  \leavevmode%
    \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
      \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{4ex}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
\vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
  \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\vfil%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\F \RL{\textbf{مسئله یادگیری دیکشنری }}} 

\author{{\setRTL \F \RL{\textbf{فلان الدین فلانی}}} }
\institute[] 
{
\F \RL{\textbf{\normalsize{ دانشگاه فلان}}} 
\medskip

}
\date{\F \RL{شهریور ۱۲۹۱}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But nothing shows up in the output as a progress bar. I'd like to know what is preventing it from showing up.

**EDIT**: I think I found the cause; when I remove this part from the code, the progress bar appears in the ouptput document.

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\f@size}{10}{7}{7}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{arabic split theme}
{

  \leavevmode%
    \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
      \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{4ex}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
\vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
  \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\vfil%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

But I really don't have a clue what this part of the code is doing because the template was a ready-to-use beamer presentation template that the university recommends to use. So what do you suggest to do?

Comment: Thank you for posting an example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Please try if you can reproduce the problem without all the special fonts. This will increase the number of people who can try to help you.

Comment: I was about to do that but then since I don't know what the source of the problem is, I cannot remove those parts. @samcarter

Comment: Hmmm, OK, I will do that. Thanks. @samcarter

Comment: That's called debugging. Remove unnecessary parts of the code, check if the problem still persists and so on. If the problem vanishes at some point, you know it is related to the code just removed.

Comment: The first headline is superfluous, try to remove it. For the second headline, defining it is not enough, you have to set it. [but I can't test if this solves the problem, as I don't have the fonts used in your example]

Comment: Offtopic comments: Don't load packages twice, this is prone to cause problems due to option clashes etc. Furthermore packages like `graphicx` are not needed in beamer, as beamer already provides these functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I voted to reopen this question. Can you check if http://pastebin.com/92sQvDMV works for you? This is how far I get without the fonts.

Comment: BTW: Can you use some longer name for the `\F` command? Single letter commands can be very troublesome.

Comment: Offtopic and I really don't know: but are you sure that combining babel and polyglossia are a good idea? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel

Comment: Thank you @samcarter. As for your first suggestion about using longer names, I will but for the second one I have no idea about the combination of the two packages and it being good or bad.

Comment: Did you try http://pastebin.com/92sQvDMV ?

Comment: @samcarter Sorry but I guess there was a problem in the code I posted earlier, please see the edited question. I apologize if it took your time.

Answer (score 5):

This is too long for a comment.

Actually @samcarter figured out the problem: this is how things go wrong

- You insert progress bar into the `headline` template by `\addtobeamertemplate`
- You define a new `headline` template called `arabic split theme` by `\defbeamertemplate*`.
- Since you are calling the starred version, BEAMER will define **and then** install this template.
- The progress bar is erased.

---

To be more precise, the official description of `\addtobeamertemplate` reads:

> This command adds the ⟨pre-text⟩ before the text that is currently installed as the template ⟨element name⟩ and the ⟨post-text⟩ after it. This allows you a limited form of modification of existing templates.
>   ...
>   If a new template is installed, any additions will be deleted. On the other hand, you can repeatedly use this command to add multiple things.

And the official description of `\defbeamertemplate` reads:

> This command installs a prede ned option for the template ⟨element name⟩. Once this command has been used, users can access the prede ned template using the `\setbeamertemplate` command.
>   ...
>   The starred version of the command installs the predefined template option, but then immediately calls `\setbeamertemplate` for this option. This is useful for the default templates.

---

So you have several choices:

- Delete `*` from `\def...`, so the new-defined style will not be installed and progress bar will remain.
- Exchange the order of `\add...` and `\def...` so nothing can erase the progress bar.
- Include the progress bar in the definition of a new template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point is I like the way outline is being showed in this theme, so I wouldn't change the theme (if that's what you meant by template) and obviously I do want to have both the progress bar and defined header.

Answer (score 2):

With some tricks from my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259181/54817) to write right to left beamer presentations, especially for lists and alignment of text.

You may need to update the package  [bidi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi)  which ensures changing the direction of the text in case of right to left languages

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}


\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\farsifontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\digitfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily{\F}[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} % Farsi
\newfontfamily{\I}[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} % Farsi
\newfontfamily{\C}{Amiri}

% right to left list
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin} 
\makeatother

% right to left triangle for label item 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt%
 \hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball] % or circle 


\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%
    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\orig@arabic\c@framenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

 \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

 \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\@arabic\inserttotalframenumber/\insertframenumber};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
   \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}
{\let\old\inserttotalframenumber%
\def\inserttotalframenumber{\@arabic\old}%
}{}
\makeatother



\title{\F\bfseries مسئله یادگیری دیکشنری } 

\author{\F\bfseries فلان الدین فلانی 
 \and 
 دانشگاه فلان } 

\date{\F  شهریور ۱۲۹۱ }  


\begin{document}
\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}

\begin{frame}
\everypar{}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{فصل أول}
\subsection{عنوان أول}
\begin{frame}{}
  متن نمونه

 \begin{itemize}\RTList
      \item مورد اول
 \end{itemize}

 \begin{enumerate}\RTList
      \item مورد اول
      \begin{enumerate}\RTList
      \item  مورد اول
      \item  مورد ثان
      \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Problem is the defined header of CambridgeUS theme which shows the outline of presentation disappears and I don't want that.

Comment: Try to update your distribution especially `bidi` and `tikz`