# How can I select a different frametitle template in beamer for the ToC frame?

Tags: beamer, themes

So while designing a beamer theme, I came across the neat solution to select page specific templates through the pagestyle ([Theme with a different footline for the titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317938/theme-with-a-different-footline-for-the-titlepage/323638#323638)). While this works for a lot of the templates, it does not work for the `frametitle` template, as you can see in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{regular}{Regular Frametitle}
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{special}{Special Frametitle}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@sectionpage{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{Special Headline}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[special]
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{Special Footline}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
This page shall have the regular frametitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
This page shall have the special headline, frametitle and footline
\makeatletter\thispagestyle{navigation@sectionpage}\makeatother
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
This page shall have the regular frametitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is, that the framtitle is different through some sort of automatic for the slide that contains `\tableofcontents` and I therefore wanted to introduce a macro that selects a special page style and then ejects `\tableofcontents`. Maybe this is not the smartest solution, but is there another way to achieve the same behaviour for the `frametitle` as with this pagestyle selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the frametitle is, that it is handled specially by beamer. As you can read on p. 75 of the current version (https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

> The frame title is not typeset immediately when the
> command `\frametitle` is encountered. Rather, the argument of the command
> is stored internally and the frame title is only typeset when the
> complete frame has been read. This gives you access to both the `⟨frame title text⟩` and to the `⟨subframe title text⟩` that is possibly introduced
> using the `\framesubtitle` command.

So basically there is some magic happening here and hence the workflow described is of no use. However I found a way to achieve my desired behavior, as you can read in [How can I automatically have a frametitle on my agenda page in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552939/how-can-i-automatically-have-a-frametitle-on-my-agenda-page-in-beamer)