# Beamer background-picture doesn't cover logo-region

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, sectioning, backgrounds, logos

My goal is to switch the backgroundtemplate for every `\AtBeginSection{}`-frame. This is working so far, but the logo-region is overlaying the background with a plain white region.

[image]

I'm using `\useoutertheme{sidebar}`. I had this problem before, when i wanted to not include an actual logo, but include the logo and the gray region in `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`. The issue was also, that the logo-region was overlaid with white. I consider the way it works right now as a hack, as i've put the gray background and the logo inside a `\tikz{}`-command inside of `\logo{}` with very obscure coordinates:

```latex
\logo{
  \tikz{
    \fill[grayborder] (-1,0) rectangle (20.7mm,1cm);
    \node at (.5cm,.5cm) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Hochschule-esslingen}};
  }
}
```

This is what my `\AtBeginSection{}`-command looks like at the moment:

```latex
\AtBeginSection[]{
  {
    \logo{}
    \useoutertheme{}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[at=(current page.south east)]
        \shadedraw[shading=axis,
          left color=left,
          right color=right,
          shading angle=135,
          middle color=right,
          vertical custom shading=35
        ]
        (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \begin{frame}
      \textcolor{white}{\MakeUppercase{\Huge\thesection\\[.4ex]\insertsectionhead}}
    \end{frame}
  }
}
```

As an added bonus, the sidebar should also be disabled for the `\AtBeginSection{}`-frame, but that might be for another question.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{right}{HTML}{002d58}
\definecolor{left}{HTML}{00aadc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hspace{10pt}\insertdate\hfill% 
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{10pt}%
  \vspace{8pt}%
}

\useoutertheme[%
  width=3cm,
  height=1cm,
  hideothersubsections,
  ]{sidebar}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  {
    \useoutertheme{} % Should deactivate outertheme temporarily
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[at=(current page.south east)]
        \shadedraw[shading=axis,
          left color=left,
          right color=right,
          shading angle=135,
        ]
        (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \begin{frame}
      \textcolor{white}{\MakeUppercase{\Huge\thesection\\[.4ex]\insertsectionhead}}
    \end{frame}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of posting code fragments, please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: @leandriis i hesitated because of the length the MWE would have. I edited the question now.

Comment: Reading the source code of `beamerouterthemesidebar.sty`, we see that the logo block is contained within a `beamercolorbox` environment, where `\usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}` is called. So, you can adjust the color of this rectangle using `\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=black}`. Overall I think this is a bad assumption by the class, and unfortunately, I don't think LaTeX supports transparent colors, so I'm not sure what you can do here.

Comment: Can i delete the logo altogether somehow? I wouldn‘t need it anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251184/how-to-redefine-a-beamer-template), i tried to redefine the beamertemplate to disable the `\logo`-region altogether.

`kpsewhich beamerouterthemesidebar.sty` yielded the location to where the stylefile is stored on disk. After that one can check for the place, the logo is defined, which in this case looked like this:

```latex
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sidebar theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \hfill%
    \fi%
    \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%
      \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
      \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
      \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
      \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
        \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
    \else%
      \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%
    \fi%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Then i included

```latex
\defbeamertemplate{headline}{dummy}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[dummy]
```

in the preamble of my document. This removed the logo throughout, which was sufficient for me.

Comment: Nice work. Just to confirm, this disables the use of the logo throughout (by the usual means). So not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Yes, i'm essentially taking away functionality. I could also include the `\setbeamertemplate`-command inside of the `AtBeginSection`-block to change it locally if i would need a logo for the regular frames.